# Iterate over a column containing keys from a dict. Return matched keys from second dict keeping order of keys from first dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have been stack with a problem for a couple of days with Python (2.7). I have 2 data sets, A and B, from 2 different populations, containing ordered positions along the chromosomes (defined by a name, e.g. rs4957684) and their corresponding frequencies in the 2 populations. Most of the positions in B match those in A. I need to get the frequencies in A and B of only those positions that match between A and B, and in the corresponding order along the chromosomes.

I created a csv file (df.csv) with 4 columns: keys from A (c1), values from A (c2), keys from B (c3), values from B (c4).

First I created 2 dicts, dA and dB, with keys and values (positions and frequencies respectively) from A and B, and looked for the keys that match between A and B. From the matched keys I generated 2 new dicts for A and B (dA2 and dB2).
The problem is that, since they are dicts, I cannot get the order of the matched positions in the chromosomes so I figured out another strategy:

Iterate along c1 and see whether any key from c3 matches the ordered keys in c1. If yes, return an ordered list with the values (of A and B) of the matched keys.

I wrote this code:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('df.csv', mode='r') as infile: # input file
# to open the file in universal-newline mode
reader = csv.reader(open('df.csv', 'rU'), quotechar='"', delimiter = ',')
dA= dict((rows[1],rows[2]) for rows in reader)
dB= dict((rows[3],rows[4]) for rows in reader)

import sys  
sys.stdout = open("df2.csv", "w") 

for key, value in dB:
    if rows[3] in dA.key():
        print rows[2], rows[4]
```

Here the script seems to run but I get no output

```
# I also tried this:
for row in reader:
    if row[3] in dA.key():
        print row[4]
```

...and I have the same problem.

Comment: Why you don't use OrderedDict?

Comment: Also take a note that you can't iterate dictionary like this: `for key, value in dB`, you should call `iteritems` method if you need both key and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you imported `OrderedDict`, but didn't use it. You should build `OrderedDict` to save keys order:

```
dict_a = OrderedDict((rows[1],rows[2]) for rows in reader)
dict_b = dict((rows[3],rows[4]) for rows in reader)

for key, value in dict_a.iteritems():
    if dict_b[key] == value:
        print value
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Eugene Soldatov !!. It worked great !